# What is supposed to be a simple TCP Client Server,, STUCK

Tags: delphi, client-server, firemonkey, indy10

I am stuck. I have previously used the server and client sockets (non-indy) and they were nicely asynchronous and easy to use. I am trying to make a simple client server. Once connected to a client the server sends out small blocks of data on a timer event. The time is 77ms and the blocks of data are approximately 100 bytes.
I have tried my best to figure out indy from bits here and there and people's examples. (Obviously there wouldn't be so much about it on the web if people could get it working quickly). Below I extracted the relevant sections from my client and server.

I have the ip set to localhost and i am trying to first debug the server side. I start the client, I start the server in the debugger. the client connects and I can put a break point at the onconnect event and the program goes there. Now what is supposed to happen is the timer is enabled and then every time it trips I send my block of data. (this doesn't happen at least in the debugger)

The compiler forced me to add an onexecute event for the server and I don't know what to do with it now. I tried a blank event and I tried a dummy readln.
On the Client side. I copied a read thread from elsewhere once there is a connection it is supposed to start and read the data blocks as they occur. Right now I am not doing any error checking or automatic detection of loss of connection and attempted re-connection.

I would certainly appreciate any help , both in getting this working and also in hints on how to handle the corner cases.

thanks
robert

Server side this is supposed to send a block of data every 77 ms
....................................................................................

```
type
  TForm8 = class(TForm)
    SendButton: TButton;
    SendWaveFormTimer: TTimer;
    IdUDPClient1: TIdUDPClient;
    IdTCPServer1: TIdTCPServer;

    procedure SendWaveFormTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);

  private
    connectedto:TIdContext;
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form8: TForm8;


procedure TForm8.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
// this is not in the main ui thread and can't call showmessage
begin
  connectedto:=acontext; // save the connected TIDcontext for use elsewhere?
  self.SendWaveFormTimer.Enabled:=true; {set the send timer}
end;

procedure TForm8.SendWaveFormTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);

var tempbyte:tidbytes;

begin
  tempbyte:=RawToBytes(WaveFormSample,sizeof(TWaveFormSample));
  form8.connectedto.Connection.IOHandler.Write(tempbyte, sizeof(TWaveFormSample));
end;

procedure TForm8.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
// again this in second thread
var recv:string;
begin
  //I don't know what to put here I am not expecting anything right now
  recv := AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadLn;

end;
```

Client Side

```
type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    IdUDPServer1: TIdUDPServer;
    Label1: TLabel;
    IdTCPClient1: TIdTCPClient;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure IdUDPServer1UDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;
    const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;


TReadingThread = class(TThread)
protected
  FConn: TIdTCPConnection;
  procedure Execute; override;
public
  constructor Create(ACon: TIdTCPConnection); reintroduce;
end;

type
  TMyNotify = class(TidNotify)
  private
    recvd_block:TWaveFormSample;
  protected
    procedure DoNotify; override;
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;
  Udp_message_ID:tmessageid;
  UDp_WaveFormSample:twaveformsample;

  ReadingThread: TReadingThread = nil;


implementation

constructor TReadingThread.Create(ACon: TIdTCPConnection);
begin
  FConn := ACon;
  inherited Create(False);
end;



procedure TForm3.IdTCPClient1Connected(Sender: TObject);
begin
  readingthread.Create(IdTCPClient1);
  readingthread.execute; //this must be wrong
end;


procedure tform3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdTCPClient1.Connect; //this works on the other end
end;


procedure TReadingThread.Execute;
var
  TCP_TWaveFormSample:twaveformsample;
  AData: TIdBytes;
  data_rdy:boolean;
  MyNotify: TMyNotify;
begin
  MyNotify := TMyNotify.Create;

  MyNotify.Notify;
  data_rdy:=false;

  while not Terminated do
  begin

    FConn.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(1000);
    FConn.IOHandler.CheckForDisconnect;
    if not FConn.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty and not data_rdy then
    begin
      fconn.iohandler.ReadBytes(Adata,sizeof(TWaveFormSample));
      Idglobal.BytesToRaw(AData, TCP_message_ID, sizeof(tmessageid)); //global load
      Idglobal.BytesToRaw(AData, TCP_TWaveFormSample, sizeof(twaveformsample));
      data_rdy:=true;
    end; // data
    If not Drawing and data_rdy then //make sure the other thread can take it
    begin
      MyNotify.recvd_block :=Udp_TWaveFormSample;
      MyNotify.Notify;
      data_rdy:=false;
    end;

  end;
end ;

procedure TMyNotify.DoNotify;
begin
  waveformunit.writenewdata (recvd_block.WaveformIndex,recvd_block.WaveformData,
  samples_per_send);
  drawing:=false;
end;
```

Comment: `readingthread.execute; //this must be wrong` Yes it is wrong. _Very_ wrong. There are plenty of questions on this site about how to use threads correctly and I suggest you start there: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdelphi%5D+thread   You have not provided a [mcve] that is "complete" or "minimal" or easily verifiable; nor have you bothered to put in the minimal effort to format your code for legibility. So I'm not inclined to put in effort to investigate further.

Answer (score 5):

`TIdTCPServer` is a multi-threaded component. Its events are fired in worker threads. Your timer does not work because `TTimer` is a message-based timer and there is no message loop in those threads to service it.

You are supposed to do your I/O work with the client in the server's `OnExecute` event, which is fired in the thread that manages the client connection, not in the main UI thread.

Everything you have shown on the server side is all wrong.  Try something more like this:

```
interface

...

type
  TForm8 = class(TForm)
    IdTCPServer1: TIdTCPServer;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form8: TForm8;

implementation

type
  TMyContext = class(TIdServerContext)
    LastSend: TIdTicks;
  end;

procedure TForm8.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdTCPServer1.ContextClass := TMyContext;
end;

procedure TForm8.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
   TMyConext(AContext).LastSend := Ticks64;
end;

procedure TForm8.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Ctx: TMyContext;
  temp: TIdBytes;
begin
  Ctx := TMyContext(AContext);

  if GetElapsedTicks(Ctx.LastSend) >= 77 then
  begin
    // grab the latest sample and send it... 
    temp := RawToBytes(Waveformsample, sizeof(TWaveFormSample));
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(temp);
    Ctx.LastSend := Ticks64;
  end;

  // in case the client sends something, just ignore it for now...
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;

  Sleep(0);
end;
```

That being said, since your server is expecting only 1 client, you might consider using `TIdSimpleServer` instead, which is not multi-threaded at all, so you can run it from the main UI thread if you want to.  But if you want to service multiple clients, stick with `TIdTCPServer`.

On the client side, everything you have shown is also all wrong. You are misusing `TThread`, the `IOHandler`, and `TIdNotify`.  Try something more like this:

```
interface

...

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    IdTCPClient1: TIdTCPClient;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    private
      { Private declarations }
    public
      { Public declarations }
    end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

type
  TReadingThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    FConn: TIdTCPConnection;
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(ACon: TIdTCPConnection); reintroduce;
  end;

  TMyNotify = class(TIdNotify)
  private
    recvd_block: TWaveFormSample;
  protected
    procedure DoNotify; override;
  end;

var
  ReadingThread: TReadingThread = nil;

constructor TReadingThread.Create(ACon: TIdTCPConnection);
begin
  FConn := ACon;
  inherited Create(False);
end;

procedure TForm3.IdTCPClient1Connected(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ReadingThread := TReadingThread.Create(IdTCPClient1);
end;

procedure Tform3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdTCPClient1.Connect;
end;

procedure TReadingThread.Execute;
var
  WaveFormSample: TWaveFormSample;
  AData: TIdBytes;
  MyNotify: TMyNotify;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    FConn.IOHandler.ReadBytes(AData, sizeof(TWaveFormSample), False);
    BytesToRaw(AData, WaveFormSample, sizeof(TWaveFormSample));
    MyNotify := TMyNotify.Create;
    MyNotify.recvd_block := WaveFormSample;
    MyNotify.Notify;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyNotify.DoNotify;
begin
  // use recvd_block as needed...
end;
```

Comment: I put in as near to Remy's code as I code get to compile.  I had to add append set to false on the  read  and the indy runtime kept giving errors when I  used the get elapsedticks function. So I used a status flag from an external counter..Everything worked dandy with 127.0.0.1,, as soon as I put it on a real network (just the two computers on it) it doesn't work worth a crap...It is loosing records. .

Comment: I will clean up my code to the essentials and post it ... but I am giving up. It sure looks to me like there are some basic bugs with Indy and 10.21 studio.  Maybe it is a thread sync problem, eg I am accessing variables from the main thread with the reader and send thread. But I have rudimentary flags set to keep that from happening on  first order. But it that is the case why the decrease in performance when switching to  real ethernet hardware vs local host?  I appreciate all of Remy's help

Comment: @rebible: good catch about the `Append` parameter. But what errors are you getting on the `GetElapsedTicks()` function? And TCP *cant* lose records, so something else has to be going on. Either you are not sending the packets correctly, or you are not reading them correctly. Indy may have some complexity/flexibility to it that you are not used to, but it is very mature and not buggy in this regard, especially at such basic layers.